# xml.etree.ElementTree - Trouble setting xmlns = '...'

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

I must be missing something. I'm attempting to set up a google product feed, but am having a hard time registering the namespace.

Example:

Directions here: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160589

Trying to insert:

```
<rss version="2.0" 
xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
```

This is the code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring

tree = ElementTree
tree.register_namespace('xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0')
top = tree.Element('top')
#... more code and stuff
```

After code is run, everything turns out fine, but we're missing the `xmlns=`

I find it easier to create XML docs in php, but I figured I'd give this a try. Where am I going wrong?

On that note, perhaps there is a more appropriate way to do this in python, not using etree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API docs for ElementTree do not make working with namespaces very clear, but it's mostly straightforward. You need to wrap elements in `QName()`, and not put `xmlns` in your namespace argument.

```
# Deal with confusion between ElementTree module and class name
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, QName, tostring
from io import BytesIO

# Factored into a constant
GOOG = 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'
ET.register_namespace('g', GOOG)

# Make some elements
top = Element('top')
foo = SubElement(top, QName(GOOG, 'foo'))

# This is an alternate, seemingly inferior approach
# Documented here: http://effbot.org/zone/element-qnames.htm
# But not in the Python.org API docs as far as I can tell
bar = SubElement(top, '{http://base.google.com/ns/1.0}bar')

# Now it should output the namespace
print(tostring(top))

# But ElementTree.write() is the one that adds the xml declaration also
output = BytesIO()
ElementTree(top).write(output, xml_declaration=True)
print(output.getvalue())
```