# How to preserve namespaces when parsing xml via ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, elementtree

Assume that I've the following XML which I want to modify using Python's `ElementTree`:

```
<root xmlns:prefix="URI">
  <child company:name="***"/>
  ...
</root>
```

I'm doing some modification on the XML file like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('filename.xml')
# XML modification here
# save the modifications
tree.write('filename.xml')
```

Then the XML file looks like:

```
<root xmlns:ns0="URI">
  <child ns0:name="***"/>
  ...
</root>
```

As you can see, the namepsace `prefix` changed to `ns0`. I'm aware of using `ET.register_namespace()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225934/xml-etree-elementtree-trouble-setting-xmlns).

The problem with `ET.register_namespace()` is that:

1. You need to know `prefix` and `URI`
2. It can not be used with default namespace.

e.g. If the xml looks like:

```
<root xmlns="http://uri">
    <child name="name">
    ...
    </child>
</root>
```

It will be transfomed to something like:

```
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="http://uri">
    <ns0:child name="name">
    ...
    </ns0:child>
</ns0:root>
```

As you can see, the default namespace is changed to `ns0`.

Is there any way to solve this problem with `ElementTree`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml.etree.ElementTree - Trouble setting xmlns = '...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225934/xml-etree-elementtree-trouble-setting-xmlns)

Comment: The dup link uses clearly `ET.register_namespace(...`. [Edit] your Question to [mcve] to show how you use it.

Comment: @stovfl It's not about preserving the namespace and didn't help me. The name space should not be hard coded, it can be `xmlns:prefix="URI"` with any prefix and URI.

Comment: The only way to preserve the namespace prefix with ElementTree is by using `register_namespace()`. If you don't like that, try lxml instead.

Comment: @mzin You need to know `prefix` and `URI` when using `register_namespace()`. As I said, `I don't want to hard code the namespace`. Is there any way to do this with `ElementTree`?

Comment: @stovfl Editted the question to clearify the problem.

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh: Read [`lxml` namespaces](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) `lxml.etree` allows you to look up the current namespaces defined for a node through the `.nsmap` property:.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42372404/407651 for a way to get the namespaces in the document.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

ElementTree will replace those namespaces' prefixes that are not registered with `ET.register_namespace`. To preserve a namespace prefix, you need to register it first before writing your modifications on a file. The following method does the job and registers all namespaces globally,

```
def register_all_namespaces(filename):
    namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])
    for ns in namespaces:
        ET.register_namespace(ns, namespaces[ns])
```

This method should be called before `ET.parse` method, so that the namespaces will remain as unchanged,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
register_all_namespaces('filename.xml')
tree = ET.parse('filename.xml')
# XML modification here
# save the modifications
tree.write('filename.xml')
```

Comment: This solution is much better than I have seen on many other questions for the same topic.  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: does this mean the xml needs to be parsed twice? or can i somehow get the ElementTree out of this process, as i do it?

Comment: @Starwarswii Yes, if you want more control on that I think you can use `XMLPullParser` with `start-ns` event, fetching namespaces and then calling `ET.register_namespace`.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I was pulling my hair out with my namespaces getting replaced after a simple tweak to the XML.

Comment: It does not matter if `register_namespace` comes before or after `ET.parse`. `register_namespace` only affects serialization, not parsing.