# Is there something wrong with my script or the XML file? I am using ElementTree in attempt to get out child attributes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

This is a shorted version of the XML file that I am trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TipsContents xmlns="http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0">
  <TipsHeader exportTime="Mon May 04 20:05:47 SAST 2020" version="6.8"/>
  <Endpoints>
    <Endpoint macVendor="SHENZHEN RF-LINK TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD." macAddress="c46e7b2939cb" status="Known">
      <EndpointProfile updatedAt="May 04, 2020 10:02:21 SAST" profiledBy="Policy Manager" addedAt="Mar 04, 2020 17:31:53 SAST" fingerprint="{}" conflict="false" name="Windows" family="Windows" category="Computer" staticIP="false" ipAddress="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
      <EndpointTags tagName="Username" tagValue="xxxxxxxx"/>
      <EndpointTags tagName="Disabled Reason" tagValue="IS_ACTIVE"/>
    </Endpoint>
     </Endpoints>
  <TagDictionaries>
    <TagDictionary allowMultiple="false" mandatory="true" defaultValue="false" dataType="Boolean" attributeName="DOMAIN-MACHINES" entityName="Endpoint"/>
    <TagDictionary allowMultiple="false" mandatory="true" defaultValue="true" dataType="Boolean" attributeName="IS_ACTIVE" entityName="Endpoint"/>
    <TagDictionary allowMultiple="true" mandatory="false" dataType="String" attributeName="Disabled Reason" entityName="Endpoint"/>
    <TagDictionary allowMultiple="false" mandatory="false" dataType="String" attributeName="Username" entityName="Endpoint"/>
  </TagDictionaries>
</TipsContents>
```

I run the following script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
f = open("Endpoint-5.xml", 'r')
tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
```

This is what my outputs look like:

```
In [8]: root = tree.getroot()                                                                                                                                                                               

In [9]: root.findall('.')                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[9]: [<Element '{http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0}TipsContents' at 0x10874b410>]

In [10]: root.findall('./TipsHeader')                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[10]: []

In [11]: root.findall('./TipsContents')                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[11]: []

In [15]: root.findall('{http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0}TipsContents//Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointProfile')                                                                                         
Out[15]: []
```

I have been following this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example
among other tutorials but I don't seem to get an output.

I have tried `from lxml import html`

My script is as follows:

```
        tree = html.fromstring(html=f)
        updatedAt = tree.xpath("//TipsContents/Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointProfile/@updatedAt")
        name = tree.xpath("//TipsContents/Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointProfile/@name")
        category = tree.xpath("//TipsContents/Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointProfile/@category")
        tagValue = tree.xpath("//TipsContents/Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointTags[@tagName = 'Username']/@tagValue") 
        active = tree.xpath("//TipsContents/Endpoints/Endpoint/EndpointTags[@tagName = 'Disabled Reason']/@tagValue")
        print("Name:",name)
```

The above attempt also returns nothing.

I am able to parse an XML document from an API and use the second attempt successfully but when I am doing this from a local file I do not get the results.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: From the docs: "`Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are ***direct children*** of the current element." (my emphasis). Also, lose the leading `./`

Comment: The document has a default namespace. You need to take that into account. One way of doing that is to use a wildcard. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154644/407651. For example, `root.findall('{*}TipsHeader')` would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your input XML contains a default namespace, so to refer to
any element you have to specify the namespace.

One of methods to do it is to define a dictionary of namespaces
(*shortcut* : *full_name*), in your case:

```
ns = {'tips': 'http://www.avendasys.com/tipsapiDefs/1.0'}
```

Then, using *findall*:

- use the appropriate shortcut before the element name (and ':'),
- pass the namespace dictionary as the second argument.

The code to do it is:

```
for elem in root.findall('./tips:TipsHeader', ns):
    print(elem.attrib)
```

The result, for your input sample, is:

```
{'exportTime': 'Mon May 04 20:05:47 SAST 2020', 'version': '6.8'}
```

As far as *root.findall('./TipsContents')* is concerned, it will return
an empty list, even if you specify the namespace as above.

The reason is that *TipsContents* is the name of the **root** node,
whereas you attempt to find an element with the same name **below** in
the XML tree, but it contains no such element.

If you want to access attributes of the root element, you can run:

```
print(root.attrib)
```

but to get something more than an empty dictionary, you have to add
some attributes to the root element (namespace is not an attribute).