# XML - Find without namespace

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

With xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:mt_queryRequest xmlns:ns0="http://x5.ru/mdm/common">
    <messageHeader>
        <reqId>6437636</reqId>
        <targetSystem>GGG</targetSystem>
        <serviceInterface>NS</serviceInterface>
        <interfaceNamespace/>
    </messageHeader>
    <Item xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">
        <MDM_ID xmlns="">897346</MDM_ID>
        <NAME xmlns="">
            <ru_RU is_delta="True" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">NANANN</ru_RU>
        </NAME>
        <SAPNAME xmlns="">
            <ru_RU xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">NANANN</ru_RU>
        </SAPNAME>
        <FULLNAME xmlns="">
            <ru_RU xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">NANANN</ru_RU>
        </FULLNAME>
        <IS_RESIDENT xmlns="">Yes</IS_RESIDENT>
        <INN xmlns="">549348892</INN>
        <KPP xmlns="">693628032</KPP>
        <CONTRAGENT_FORM xmlns="">UL</CONTRAGENT_FORM>
        <CONTRAGENT_GROUP occ="6543234" xmlns="">
            <GROUP xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">Sub (Z013)</GROUP>
            <SAPCODE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">8012312</SAPCODE>
            <IS_ARCHIVE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">No</IS_ARCHIVE>
            <GROUP_ID xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">P013</GROUP_ID>
            <IS_ARCHIVE_ID xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">0</IS_ARCHIVE_ID>
        </CONTRAGENT_GROUP>
        <NAMES_HISTORY occ="1715174529" xmlns="">
            <SAPNAME xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01">
                <ru_RU xmlns="">Ghcsjdhc</ru_RU>
            </SAPNAME>
        </NAMES_HISTORY>
        <NORMALIZATION_STATUS xmlns="">Normalized</NORMALIZATION_STATUS>
        <CONTRAGENT_FORM_ID xmlns="">3</CONTRAGENT_FORM_ID>
        <IS_RESIDENT_ID xmlns="">1</IS_RESIDENT_ID>
    </Item>
</ns0:mt_queryRequest>
```

I had to use namespace in path:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
res = xml.find('.//{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01}Item/CONTRAGENT_GROUP/{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01}GROUP')')
```

As you can see namespace in path is hardcoded and I'm afraid that namespace could be change or there will be more than one namespace (somehow, I don't know).

Whether it possible to get rid of namespace? The only way I found is to convert xml to dict by [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) lib and work with dict.

Comment: It is possible to use namespace wildcards: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154644/407651

Comment: The root element of your xml is missing, therefore you see a ns0: prefix. Maybe you can add the root to your xml example.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, if the namespace changes then all bets are off, because when the namespace changes, everything else potentially changes too. It's only the namespace that tells you what kind of XML document this is.

You seem to be using (and are being advised to use) some non-standard extensions to XPath 1.0. In XPath 2.0 you can find elements by namespace URI and local name using the syntax

```
//Q{http://www.ibm.com/mdm/entry01}Item
```

and by local name alone with the syntax

```
//*:Item
```

But I don't think these are supported in ElementTree.

Answer (score 1):

You can search like:

```
res = root.find('.//{*}GROUP')
print(res.text)
```

Output:

```
Sub (Z013)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath `lxml` capabilities, `local-name()` xpath function would help to find elements regardless of their namespace

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse("tmp.xml")
>>> grp = doc.xpath('.//*[local-name()="Item"]/CONTRAGENT_GROUP/*[local-name()="GROUP"]')
>>> print(grp[0].text)
Sub (Z013)
```